# Why does Code Analysis fire CA2000 on this method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Visual Studio Code Analysis generates the warning "Dispose objects before losing scope" (CA2000) on the `monitor` variable in this method.

```
private void MonitorJob(IJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var monitor = new JobMonitor(job, _backend);  // <- CA2000
    try
    {
        var task = monitor.Run(cancellationToken);
        _activeJobs[task] = monitor;
    }
    catch
    {
        monitor.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I understand what CA2000 does, and I'm usually able to work out why my code violates the rule and make the appropriate changes.

In this case, however, I'm stumped - is this really a false positive, or am I missing something?

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, targeting .NET 4.5, using C# 6.

Comment: It is not obvious to a tool that the Run() method will *always* throw an exception.  Or that it might be disposed later because you store it in _activeJobs, assuming you do.  Just suppress the warning.

Comment: What's the reason of not using `using`?

Comment: @qxg how would you use it here?

Comment: @zerkms `using(var monitor = new JobMonitor()) { var task ... }`. monitor will be disposed and exception will be thrown.

Comment: @qxg any chance you have noticed this `_activeJobs[task] = monitor;` line?

Comment: Replacing the *catch* with a *finally* would mean the monitors sorted in `_activeJobs` were inactive; not the required behaviour.

Comment: @zerkms, my bad. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Your code will dispose off the resource only in case of an Exception. What about normal flow.

Therefore, it is done in a `finally` block. But that does not mean to remove the `catch` block.

So the ideal flow is `try` for some action, `catch` if something goes wrong, `finally` react as if nothing happened - in the sense no resource was ever requested :D

Comment: @RaviTiwari Normal flow is to create the monitor and trigger it running asynchronously. Both the `Task` and the `JobMonitor` are then stored in the dictionary `_activeJobs` for use elsewhere. The monitor **must not** be disposed in this case - I added the catch to ensure it's cleaned up if `Run()` throws, but only in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leak this disposable if an exception is thrown here:

```
private void MonitorJob(IJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var monitor = new JobMonitor(job, _backend);

    // <- Exception

    try
    {
        var task = monitor.Run(cancellationToken);
        _activeJobs[task] = monitor;
    }
    catch
    {
        monitor.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

This could be caused by say a `ThreadAbortException` or any other exception that's injected into a thread by the runtime. I'd suggest declaring the variable outside of the `try` block but assign it within. Also, set it to `null` on successfully assigning it to `_activeJobs`.

```
private void MonitorJob(IJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    JobMonitor monitor;

    try
    {
        monitor = new JobMonitor(job, _backend);
        var task = monitor.Run(cancellationToken);
        _activeJobs[task] = monitor;
        monitor = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(monitor!=null)
        {
            monitor.Dispose();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Even then though, it may not be enough to shut up the warning, at which point I'd suggest adding a suppression for it.

Comment: This all makes sense, but leaves me with a (minor) followup question: Why doesn't *other* code in the same project that also follows the pattern `var x = new Y(); try..catch` also violate CA2000?

Comment: For example, the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663477/30280 has exactly this structure in suggested "safe" version of `CreateFirstObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `_activeJobs[task] = monitor;` is a simple assignment and doesn't throw exception. If so separate storing monitor from creating monitor.

```
private void MonitorJob(IJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task task;
    var monitor = CreateJobMonitor(job, _backend, out task);
    _activeJobs[task] = monitor;
} 

private JobMonitor CreateJobMonitor(IJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken, out Task task)
{
    var monitor = new JobMonitor(job, _backend);
    try
    {
        task = monitor.Run(cancellationToken);
        return monitor;
    }
    catch
    {
        monitor.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
```

This way, CreateJobMonitor means either returning a valid object or throwing exception. There is no chance to return disposed object reference.